# Using context in react but they are not loading. I get TypeError: render is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the state of users to display them in the posts page, but it does not render anything, I get an error "render is not a function". Any help is highly appreciated. This is my front end

This is my code:

```
function PostsList(props) {
 
    let { deletePosts } = useContext(PostsContext);

    let users = useContext(UserContext);

    let formatDate=(input)=>{
        let v=new Date(input);
        return v.toLocaleDateString("en-US")
    }

    return (
        <PostsContext.Consumer value={users}>
            <UserContext.Consumer>
         {
            ({ posts }) => {
                return <div>
                    <h3>welcome back,  {users.name}</h3>
                    <a href="/posts/new"><button>Add New Post</button></a>
                    <div>
                        {posts.map((c) => {
                            console.log(posts)
                            return (
                                <div className='posts_list'>
                                <div key={c._id}>
                                </div>
                                <div className='posts_text'>
                                    <h2>{c.name}</h2>
                                </div>
                                    <div className='list'>
                                    <Link to={`/edit/${c._id}`}>
                                    <button>Edit</button>
                                    </Link>
                                    <button onClick={() => { deletePosts(c._id)}}>Delete</button>
                                    <p>Tweet created on: {formatDate(c.createdAt)}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        }
        </UserContext.Consumer>
        </PostsContext.Consumer>
    );
}

export default PostsList;
```

Comment: A `.Consumer` would not have a `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Consumer` component of a context is intended to be used in class components because we cannot use the useContext hook in a class component. So, you could remove the Consumer as you are using the `useContext` hook.

You will have to wrap your `PostList` component with the context providers somewhere in the parent like the following:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={someValue}>
      <PostsContext.Provider value={someValue}>
        <PostList />
      </PostsContext.Provider>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then, you can use the context like the following:

```
function PostList() {
  const users = useContext(UserContext);

  // I am assuming you get posts from "PostsContext" itself
  const { deletePosts, posts } = useContext(PostsContext);

  const formatDate = (input) => new Date(input).toLocaleDateString("en-US")

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>welcome back,  {users.name}</h3>
      <a href="/posts/new"><button>Add New Post</button></a>
      <div>
        {posts.map((c) => {
          console.log(posts)
          return (
            <div className='posts_list'>
              <div key={c._id}></div>
              <div className='posts_text'>
                <h2>{c.name}</h2>
              </div>
              <div className='list'>
                <Link to={`/edit/${c._id}`}>
                  <button>Edit</button>
                </Link>
                <button onClick={() => { deletePosts(c._id)}}>
                  Delete
                </button>
                <p>
                  Tweet created on: {formatDate(c.createdAt)}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```